# Django load object in case Unique key is Duplicate

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following Model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 slug = models.CharField(max_length=128L, unique=True, blank=True)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=128L, blank=True)
 model_slug = models.CharField(max_length=128L, unique=True, blank=True)
 ...
```

Whenever I'm getting a list of `Car` from an XML file, some of them show up multiple times 
(with the same slug), if I try to save that, I get
 `IntegrityError(1062, "Duplicate entry 'car-slug' for key 'slug'")`

I want it to load the existing Car (or updated it, whichever is easier) in case there's a Duplicate error. 
But I want it to be generic enough so that it would work for model_slug (or any unique field that generates that error).

Comment: I ended up writing https://gist.github.com/kidsil/5658666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom save on the model (so that my code doesn't change, just the model):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except IntegrityError, e:
        existing_object = Car.objects.get(slug=self.slug)
        self = existing_object
        super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return existing_object.id
```

Now I return the object's ID to assign it so the save() command looks like this:

```
the_id = generic_object.save() #e.g. Car
if the_id:
    generic_object.id = the_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
car,created = Car.objects.get_or_create(slug='car-slug')
if created:
   print 'New car was created'
   car.slug = 'new-car-slug'
else:
   # do whatever needs to be done here
   # with the existing car object, which will
   # be car
   # car.name = 'new name'

car.save()
```

Whatever arguments you provide to `get_or_create`, it will use those to search existing records for the model.

---

Suppose you don't know what combination of fields will trigger a duplicate. The easy way is to find out which fields in your model have that restriction (ie `unique=True`). You can introspect this information from your model, or a simpler way is to simply pass these fields to `get_or_create`.

First step is to create a mapping between your XML fields and your model's fields:

```
xml_lookup = {}
xml_lookup = {'CAR-SLUG': 'slug'}  # etc. etc.
```

You can populate this will all fields if you want, but my suggestion is to populate it only with those fields that have a unique constraint on them.

Next, while you are parsing your XML, populate a dictionary for each record, mapping each field:

```
for row in xml_file:
    lookup_dict = {}
    lookup_dict[xml_lookup[row['tag']] = row['value']  # Or something similar
    car, created = Car.objects.get_or_create(**lookup_dict)
    if created:
       # Nothing matched, a new record was created
       # Any any logic you need here
    else:
       # Existing record matched the search parameters
       # Change/update whatever field to prevent the IntegrityError
       car.model_slug = row['MODEL_SLUG']
       # Set/update fields as required
    car.save()  # Save the modified object
```

Comment: Sadly this solution is not generic enough for me, since the slug could be different but the model_slug is the same, in which case it will still raise an IntegrityError. I'm trying to be as none-specific as possible (no field names)

Comment: Just add and modify the filters directly? The only other way is for you to wrap everything in a try/except - which really is silly. So what you do is you wrap your XML logic around this snippet. Whenever you read a record from the XML file, check to see if an object exists with either `slug`, or `model-slug` - retrive it if it exists, or create a new one if it doesn't (that's what `get_or_create` will do); and thus you'll avoid the integrity errors.  You can also splat (by using `**dict`) and then search for _every_ field in the model.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the duplicates car entries in memory first and then invoke create on new items, e.g,

```
uniq_attrs = ['slug', 'model_slug', ...]
existed_attrs = set()
for car in car_list:
    # skip the duplicates
    if any([(attr, car[attr]) in existed_attrs for attr in uniq_attrs):
        continue
    uniq_attrs.update([(attr, car[attr]) for attr in uniq_attrs])

    # save the new car to db
    Car.objects.save(....)
```

or you can try get_or_create on unique fields and then save other attribues with model save, e.g.,

```
for car in car_list:
    attr_dict = {attr:car[attr] for attr in uniq_attrs}
    car, created = Car.objects.get_or_create(**attr_dict)

    # already created before
    if created:
        continue

    # save other attributes
    car.set(...)
    car.set(...)
    car.save()
```